# Is this correct? Solving systems of equations using Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$$x' = -y$$
$$y' = x -y$$
$$x(0) = 1$$
$$y(0) = 2$$

Full Work:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: You have $x'(t) = 6e^{-2t}$ which is not $-y(t)$, so no.

Comment: Use $x(t)$ and $X(s)$ in your work not $X$ for both, you will just confuse yourself. Laplace transform both DE's to start with to get $sX-x(0) = -Y$ and $sY-y(0) = X-Y$ then go from there. Don't use = unless both things are equal, or you will again just confuse yourself.